# Integral of inverse of Polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to create a program that calculates

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}{\frac{dx}{P(x)}}$$ , where $P(x)=ax^3+bx+cx+d$, $a,b,c$ and $d$ are real. I also assume that $P$ is strictly positive on $[x_1,x_2]$.

I had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions, but it did not really help me. I feel that the positive condition on $P$ should help to get a closed form formula.

Comment: Are you looking for numeric approximations or automates symbolic manipulation?

Comment: if the numeric approximation is fast and accurate , I will be glad to hear about it

Comment: I think that if you could write the $P(x)$ as $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$ then you could possibly use partial fractions to obtain a closed from.